# Ignore invalid ssl certificates i-phone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to ignore invalid ssl certificates when making https requests for i-phone apps?

I have an ios developer working on an app of mine and I find it hard to believe when he says this is not possible. I would appreciate it if anyone could clarify this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 9, SSL connections will fail for invalid or self-signed certs. This is part of the new  [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) protocol.

You can override this behavior in the `Info.plist`, by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES` in the `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary.

However, no production bound app should opt into this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Woodstocks answer, you may need to add `NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` and `NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>some.domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```